# how to fix an output not displaying the new value for stopwatch

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a stopwatch in vanilla JS and the code for starting the stopwatch isn't working. No errors are returning in the console so it's an error on my side. I think it's in the startTime() function or startInterval() function. Its probably something super basic that I'm not seeing. any help would be amazing, thanks friends :).

```js
let time = 0;
function timeToString() {
  let diffInHrs = time / 3600000;
  let hh = Math.floor(diffInHrs);

  let diffInMin = (diffInHrs - hh) * 60;
  let mm = Math.floor(diffInMin);

  let diffinSec = (diffInMin - mm) * 60;
  let ss = Math.floor(diffinSec);

  let formattedHH = hh.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let formattedMM = mm.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let formattedSS = ss.toString().padStart(2, "0");

  return (formattedHH + ":" + formattedMM + ":" + formattedSS);
}

let startButton = document.getElementById("startWatch");

let startTime;
let elapsedTime;

startButton.addEventListener("click", function start() {
  startTime = Date.now();

  setInterval(function printTime() {
    elapsedTime = (Date.now() - startTime);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = timeToString(elapsedTime);
  }
), 1000 });

function stop() {
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
}
```

```css
input {
  position: absolute center;

  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px, 8px;
  padding: 0.75rem 5rem;

  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(400px, 400px);
  text-decoration: none;

  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(255, 168, 0);

  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 150%;
}

input:hover {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;

  background-color: rgb(255, 211, 99);
}

#output {
  display: inline-block;

  width: 435px;
  padding: 0.75rem 5rem;

  transform: translate(404px, 350px);
  text-align: center;

  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: rgb(255, 168, 0);
    }
  </style>
  <!--styles-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output">00:00:00</div>
    <form class="watch" action="index.html" method="post">
      <input type="button" id="startWatch" value="Start">
      <input type="button" id="resetWatch" value="Reset">
      <input type="button" id="stopWatch" value="Stop">
    </form>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove your `let time = 0;` and add parameter `time` into `timeToString` as `function timeToString(time)`.

There are few more enhancements added in answer. Comments are mentioned there.

- Retrieved resetButton & stopButton using `document.getElementById` & assign click events.
- Took new object `let interval;`, Use interval object to hold object returned from setInterval which will later to be used to stop interval.
- Inside `startButton.addEventListener` added `clearInterval(interval);` before `setInterval` otherwise what would happen is when you click second time on start it will start new interval and there will be two intervals running at same time. So your watch would perform change twice in 1 second. On third click it will run three intervals at same time and watch would perform change three times in 1 second, and so on.
- Use `interval = setInterval(function printTime() {`. Set `interval` to return value from `setInterval`. And it can be used with `clearInterval(interval)` to stop interval.
- Added `clearInterval(interval);` inside `stop()`.
- Added `startTime = Date.now();` inside `reset()`, so it will start displaying tine from 0 again.

```js
 // Add time parameter
function timeToString(time) {
  let diffInHrs = time / 3600000;
  let hh = Math.floor(diffInHrs);

  let diffInMin = (diffInHrs - hh) * 60;
  let mm = Math.floor(diffInMin);

  let diffinSec = (diffInMin - mm) * 60;
  let ss = Math.floor(diffinSec);

  let formattedHH = hh.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let formattedMM = mm.toString().padStart(2, "0");
  let formattedSS = ss.toString().padStart(2, "0");

  return (formattedHH + ":" + formattedMM + ":" + formattedSS);
}

let startButton = document.getElementById("startWatch");
// Get reset and stop buttons by id
let resetButton = document.getElementById("resetWatch");
let stopButton = document.getElementById("stopWatch");

let startTime;
let elapsedTime;
let interval; // Use interval object to hold object returned from setInterval which will later to be used to stop interval.

startButton.addEventListener("click", function start() {
  startTime = Date.now();

  // Clear interval to stop interval hold by interval object.
  clearInterval(interval);

  // Set interval object to return value from setInterval.
  interval = setInterval(function printTime() {
    elapsedTime = (Date.now() - startTime);
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = timeToString(elapsedTime);
  }), 1000
});

// Add reset and stop click event listners
resetButton.addEventListener("click", reset);
stopButton.addEventListener("click", stop);

function stop() {
  // Clear interval to stop interval hold by interval object.
  clearInterval(interval);
}

function reset() {
  // Reset startTime also, so it will start displaying tine from 0
  startTime = Date.now();
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
}
```

```css
input {
  position: absolute center;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0px, 8px;
  padding: 0.75rem 5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(400px, 400px);
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: rgb(255, 168, 0);
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 150%;
}

input:hover {
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  background-color: rgb(255, 211, 99);
}

#output {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 435px;
  padding: 0.75rem 5rem;
  transform: translate(404px, 350px);
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Stopwatch</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: rgb(255, 168, 0);
    }
  </style>
  <!--styles-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="output">00:00:00</div>
  <form class="watch" action="index.html" method="post">
    <input type="button" id="startWatch" value="Start">
    <input type="button" id="resetWatch" value="Reset">
    <input type="button" id="stopWatch" value="Stop">
  </form>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```